# systemd timer OnUnitActiveSec vs OnCalendar for anacron replacement

Tags: systemd

I need to run oneshot bash script once a day (log rotation and cleaning). I saw some examples stated to use:

```
OnCalendar=daily
Persistent=true
```

and another examples using:

```
OnBootSec=20min
OnUnitActiveSec=1d
```

What is more optimal for anacron-a-like behaviour?

Comment: FWIW Arch's `logrotate.timer` is the former (but also with `AccuracySec=12h`). However, `systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer` is the latter (but with `OnBootSec=15min`).

Comment: Note that the [`OnUnitActiveSec=`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176514/is-it-correct-that-systemd-timer-accuracysec-parameter-make-the-ticks-slip) slips. CRON never slipped, it would avoid execution if a previous run was still active, but always tick at he right time otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anacron-like behavior, you'll want to use the former, where you specify a certain time and have it track when the task was last run (and to run it if it missed a run). The latter says to run the task 20 minutes after the system was booted, and then every 24 hours thereafter.

However, in my opinion, you should determine which one to use on a task-by-task basis, whether the task needs to run daily (at a specific time), or if it needs to run relative to some system event.